# How to debug a jumpy web UI

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a question about debugging procedure; I'm having a problem with a scrollable div that jumps to the top of its content every time that I receive a response from the server.  This was initially just a nuisance, but now it's causing a Select2 widget of mine to display incorrectly when it receives its results from the server.

I'm using a proprietary, homegrown client-server architecture developed within my company, and based off of jQuery on the client-side.  The codebase is massive, it has a number of side effects that occur when information is received, and I have no idea where to even look to find what code is causing this.

So I'm wondering if anyone here has any creative ideas on how I can debug this issue.  So far I have tried commenting out the code that I guessed was causing the issue (apparently it wasn't), as well as tracing the code starting from the receipt of data from the server.

Comment: Try narrowing it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, we can't really help that much as we don't have a starting place.

Comment: Yeah, thanks; that's why I was asking about general debugging procedures that I could follow for a large codebase rather than asking for help on specifically finding the problem in my code.  But thanks for the link :-); I might be able to do something similar to divide and conquor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug using a form of divide and conquer (thanks @Kevin Brown for the link).  Effectively I placed a break point at a central loop in the software, and as the loop progressed, I was able to see visually the point at which the UI jumped.  Once I had the particular iteration determined (by console.log()), I was able to further narrow down the source of the bug.